# Search vector elements in collection of vectors

Tags: clojure

I have a vector fo keywords and I have a collection of vectors with actual data, what I want to do is search each keyword and return true if any vector contains that keyword. For now, I have implementation only for one keyword, but I cannot make it work for the vector of keywords. I am very new in Clojure, so any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Here is my code so far:

```
(def results (apply map vector [["test1" "test2"] ["test3" "test4" "test5"]]))
(defn in?
  "true if coll contains elm"
  [coll]
  (some #(= "test4" %) coll))

  (println (map #(in? %) results))
```

but I want something like this:

```
    (def searchwords ["test3" "test2"])
    (def results (apply map vector [["test1" "test2"] ["test3" "test4" "test5"]]))
    (defn in?
      "true if coll contains elm"
      [coll keyword]
      (some #(= keyword %) coll))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what are you trying to achieve? Example inputs and outputs would be helpful.

Comment: For example for now in? function returns (nil, true), this means that "test4" was found in second vector, what I want to achieve is that whenever (some #(= keyword %) coll) returns true to change keyword searched again

Comment: Please, provide example inputs and expected outputs for function you need to implement. Append them right to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
(defn search
   [coll keyword]
   (println (flatten coll))
   (if (= (flatten coll) (list keyword))
     true))

(defn in?
   [coll keyword]
   (map #(search % %2) coll keyword))    

(in? results searchwords)
;=> (true)
```

This only works if searchwords is ["test2"] and results is [["test2"]].
Maybe if you can figure out a way to iterate through results using `in?`.

P.s Also new to clojure.